# 8051 microcontroller kit recommendation?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, avr, 8051, mikroc

I'm a first year Computer Science student looking to get started with development for micro-controllers. I'd like to use the 8051, as it's common as dirt, and is used frequently in the real world.

During my junior or senior year, I'll be taking a PIC micro-controller based embedded design class, so I'd rather not do PIC now; otherwise, I'll be fairly bored during that course.

Most commercial kits I see are for the AVR or PIC series of microprocessors. I'm just looking for something with decent development tools, documentation, and enough add-ons to keep my novice self occupied for the summer.

Any recommendations for an 8051 family kit? Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged avr and pic?

Comment: This question was [reposted at chiphacker.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2722), but an edit to the question specifies that the advice of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876361/8051-microcontroller-kit-recommendation/2887003#2887003) was followed.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the MCUniversity ToolStick development kit from Silicon Labs:

http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/MCUniversity.aspx

Disclaimer: I work for Silicon Labs.

The kit and documentation are designed for people who are new to the 8051 and microcontrollers in general.

Comment: I ended up going with the MCUniversity kit, as per your recommendation. The documentation and coursework looks very well suited for someone at my level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I asked pretty much the same question on a microcontroller forum.  The original post is [here](http://www.cygnal.org/ubb/Forum4/HTML/001061.html).  The recommendation is for the F340DK from silabs.com.  I was looking at silabs because I had heard they had good kits.  This runs about $70-$100 depending on where you get it.

Comment: Those kits look pretty nice. What other components would you recommend buying as well? Are there any project guides?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, that is as far as I have gotten being a total newbie as well.  I was just going to buy it and see what I could do with the basic kit and then assess what else I would need.  The silabs kits were recommended by a person who makes hardware for iPhones.

Answer (score 2):

Mikroelektronika make some pretty cool boards...
Pretty feature-packed. Been using the PIC flavour and I love it.

The MikroC IDE is good, board has plenty of addons and features
What else could you need :D

Check out their 8051 devboard here
http://www.mikroe.com/eng/products/view/329/easy8051-v6-development-system/